# Invoking two commands at the same time powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I would like to invoke two commands at the same time when entering parameters so for example if I was to execute this code I would put:

`abcdef folder1 folder2`

and it would make two folders on the desktop.

The code below is just an example but I want to know the correct syntax for doing it.

```
function abcdef {
  param($folder1, $folder2)
  $s = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock("mkdir C:\'Documents and Settings'\X\Desktop\$folder1")
  $s1 = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock("mkdir C:\'Documents and Settings'\X\Desktop\$folder2")
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerRemote -ScriptBlock $s,$s1 -Credential $cred 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function abcdef {
param(
 [parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
 [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty]
 [String[]] $ComputerName,
 [parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
 [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
 [string[]] $folders,
 [parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2)]
 [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
 [PSCredential] $cred
)

 foreach($computer in $ComputerName){
   foreach($folder in $folders{
   $s = { New-Item "C:\Documents and Settings\X\Desktop\$folder" -type directory }
   Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock $s -Credential $cred 
   }
 }

}
```

You can call the function like this:

```
abcdef $computernames $folders $credentials
```

Or you can pipe Computernames like this to do the action on all computers your previous command returns (in this example all AD Computers):

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | abcdef $folders $credentials
```

Also notice that i dont use `mkdir`, you should allways use cmdlets if one is available for the action you are trying to execute

Comment: Thanks but what if i wanted to do two completely different commands? for e.g. one to create a folder and another change an ip address. all in one function

Comment: in that case you would define a second scriptblock with the other action and call Invoke-Command again or add the action to the first scriptblock (which i would advise you not to do)

Comment: I will try it out and let you know how it goes. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do this by declaring a folder parameter as a string array:

```
function abcdef {
    param([string[]]$Folder)
}
```

And then you do a foreach of the contents of this array:

```
foreach ($f in $Folder) {
    # do something with $f
}
```

You invoke this function like this:

```
abcdef 'folder1','folder2'
```

or

```
abcdef -Folder @('folder1','folder2')
```